# Pandas : create a list based on index of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**I am trying to obtain a list from a Dataframe based on a common value of the index.**

In the example below I am trying to obtain the lists for **'type'** and **'xx'** based on **'date'**.

Here is the Dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = [np.array(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar']),np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A1', 'A3', 'A4'])]
data = [{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 5}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx'])
df.index.names=['date','type']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df=df.set_index(['date'])
```

Which looks like this:

```py
      type  xx
date        
 Jan    A1   1
 Jan    A2   5
 Feb    A2   3
 Mar    A1   2
 Mar    A3   7
 Mar    A4   3
```

What I am trying to do is to create these two lists:

```py
#list_type
[['A1', 'A2'], ['A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']]

#list_xx
[['1', '5'], ['3'], ['2', '7', '3']]
```

As you can see, the elements of the lists are constructed based on a common date.

**I would really value an efficient way of doing this in Python.**

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with list and then convert `DataFrame` to dictionary of lists by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).agg(list).to_dict('l')
print (d)
{'type': [['A1', 'A2'], ['A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']], 'xx': [[1, 5], [3], [2, 7, 3]]}

print (d['type'])
[['A1', 'A2'], ['A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']]

print (d['xx'])
[[1, 5], [3], [2, 7, 3]]
```